# Unexpected token ) <===

Tags: javascript

I am hooking up flexslider into a custom Wordpress theme but running into an issue within my JS which is strange.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function)($) {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
});
```

It is telling me there is an unexpected token of ) but I can't see the offending part of script?

Comment: Typo: There's an extra `)` after the `function` keyword -- `...ready(function ($) { ... });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mixed up your parentheses:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function)($) {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
});
```

should be:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
});
```